# Dependency injection lwc compoenent

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is it possible to do dependency injection on lwc components so I can pass the service in the constructor? I would like to put all the @wireservice in one commond service so I don't need to write the same code everywhere

Comment: You could use inheritance; a base component with the common properties and wires then extend this in your actual LWC components. There are, however, [limitations](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/248180/how-can-we-expose-inherited-properties-from-a-super-component-s-class-in-a-light). Alternatively, you might be able to use composition, using a "service component" within the LWC you write, where the LWC sets API properties on the service to trigger the wire, and have the service raise events to send data back...

Comment: Thanks, any example to create the service component and inject into the UI component?

Comment: Could you create a component that exports the functions you want, then import it to where you need it?